# IBM Watson TTS cURL request : how to have diacritic / accentend characters recognised?

Tags: curl, diacritics, non-ascii-characters

How do I make Watson manage french accented characters in the POST request ? I tried to add the utf-8 mention but with no result.

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:###hidden### " ^
--header "Content-Type: application/json; charset: utf-8" ^
--header "Accept: audio/wav" ^
--data "{\"text\":\"Nous sommes le 18 décembre 2019.\"}" ^
--output text.wav ^
"https://api.eu-gb.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/###hidden###/v1/synthesize?voice=fr-FR_ReneeVoice"
```

the result text. wav is :

```
"code_description": "Bad Request", 
   "code": 400, 
   "error": "'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 20: invalid start byte"
```

I suppressed the utf-8 mention and tried to replace --data by --data-urlencode but I get another error :

```
 "code_description": "Bad Request", 
   "code": 400, 
   "error": "No JSON object could be decoded"
}
```

Comment: Curl simply transmits whatever bytes you put there. I guess the error message is revealing that your local encoding is not UTF-8 and judging from the error message it's probably something like a Windows code page (yuck). See also the [guidance in the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page.](/tags/character-encoding/info)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

1. save the text in a separate json file, say "text_to_read.json"
2. rewrite the --data line as follows :

`--data @"text_to_read.json"`